# ffserver "dimensions not set" when loading stream

Tags: ffmpeg, ffserver

I am live streaming a webcam from my raspberry pi using avconv (ffmpeg "replacement")

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -v debug -r 5 -s 176x144 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec mjpeg http://192.168.0.3:8090/feed1.ffm
```

to my local network OSX machine (for testing) running ffserver

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000
CustomLog -
NoDaemon

<Feed feed1.ffm>
   File feed1.ffm
   FileMaxSize 20M
   ACL allow 192.168.0.10
</Feed>

<Stream test.mjpeg>
   Feed feed1.ffm
   Format mjpeg
   NoAudio
   VideoQMin 1
   VideoQMax 10
   VideoSize 176x144
   VideoFrameRate 5
</Stream>
```

When I start avconv it appears to be streaming to ffserver fine:

```
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://192.168.0.3:8090/feed1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.1
    Stream #0.0, 0, 1/1000000: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, 1/5, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 5 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mjpeg)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=  108 fps= 18 q=21.7 size=     688kB time=21.60 bitrate= 260.9kbits/s
```

And the ffserver status page shows the stream

[image: ffserver status]

However when I load `http://localhost:8090/test.mjpeg` in VLC it doesn't play and ffserver spits out:

```
Sat May 25 17:25:34 2013 dimensions not set
Sat May 25 17:25:34 2013 Error writing output header
Sat May 25 17:25:34 2013 127.0.0.1 - - [GET] "/test.mjpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 66
```

I've tried so many different configurations and settings, I'm at a loss to what is causing that error!

Thank you

Comment: why was this closed as "off topic"!? Especially with zero feedback as to why...

Comment: I think it could be because this question is about configure a server, and SO is about programming questions. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Maybe this question should be on another Stackexchange site.

Comment: But if you read any of the related questions, hell try the top one, it's almost identical, yet it has 7 responses... ffserver is all about configuration, why have the tag if we can't ask questions about it